# Better user agent library for Codeigniter

Tags: codeigniter

I am looking for a more advanced user agent detection library for Codeigniter.
I want to add short tags for OS, Browser and Browser version to the body tag so
that I am able to write CSS that is gear towards different browsers and platforms.

Like this:

```
<body id="Win7 IE9">
```

Right now the default agent detection library for CI produces this:

```
<body id="Windows 7 Internet Explorer 9.22.2">
```

How can I "shorten" the response?

This is want I am looking to achieve: http://www.contao.org/en/blog/forget-about-browser-hacks-in-contao-210.html

Thankful for all input!

Answer (score 1):

I don't think that user agent library is bad. It just do what it is supposed to do.
Maybe you should build a small helper or extend the user agent library, this is really simple task (you should look at `agent->browser()`, `agent->version`, `agent->platfrom()` etc.)

Despite what Contao says, these are browser hacks. Better way is to build your style sheets and/or javascript the right way (without this type of hacks). I don't ever needed different stylesheets (or browser specific classes) for different browsers.

Comment: How do you get away with one ss and no browser info? I get that you start with boiler plate to avoid padding issues, etc but What if you want to use html5 features? requires different behaviors and display for older browsers. What if you want to optimize for mobile? media queries only work with css3? How can you accommodate these sort of things without any user agent information? (genuine question - looking for pointers)

Comment: Browser sniffing is very bad practise. And why should I use more stylesheets? I am not using any modernizr-boilerplate frameworks/packages.
Right now, I am optimizing large website for mobile devices and media queries are working pretty well (also on old devices).
I don't need different behaviours for older browsers, I am not into this "html5" hype. I am using all things, that I need to use (html5 video, some nice css3 features) and my webpages are degrading gracefully in older browsers.

Comment: I didnt think media queries worked below ie9 without a javascript based shiv which presumably relies on some form of browser sniffing (perhaps not)

Comment: I am using media queries only for mobile browsers. For web browsers I don't need any hacks/helpers.

Answer (score 1):

I see what you are trying to do. To get away with this using CodeIgniter you'll have to basically rewrite the user agent library to return your shorter user agent strings (its time consuming but not too difficult)(the four user agent arrays are in: system/libraries/user_agents.php).

Answer (score 0):

Its been more than a year since this question was asked but i am sure it will help someone in future. User agents names are defined in `./application/config/user_agents.php` file in an associative array format you can change the value of array with the one you want.

**Note:** Changing the value in config file will reflect in the entire application. If you want to change in a particular area of application i would suggest to create your own function.

Answer (score -1):

Try this

**$this->session->userdata['user_agent'];**